# Minikube on Windows and HyperV: Stuck on prompt "minikube login"

Tags: hyper-v, minikube, chocolatey

I'm "extremely" new to Kubernetes, and I wanted to try it out on my local machine, which is running Windows 10 along with HyperV. I saw that `minikube` is used for local development, and I was able to find in on `Chocolatey`, so I installed it using that:

```
choco install minikube -y
```

(I think this also installs `kubectl`)

The problem I have is that I'm not able to start it; I'm running the following command:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv
```

I have *an* external switch configured in HyperV (I found it as a suggestion somewhere), but when I run the command, it's stuck in `Creating VM ...`

I thought maybe it would give me a clue if I look at the VM created in HyperV,  and when I open that, I see the following:
[image]

So, it seems that it's waiting for input, and that's why it's stuck! I tried searching for the problem, but to no avail.

I would appreciate any help

PS: It seems to me that if I wait long enough, the following message appears on the console:

```
Temporary Error: provisioning: error getting ssh client: Error dialing
    tcp via ssh client: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, 
    attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, somehow by chance, I think I found how to resolve the issue.

First thing is that: the fact the VM is displaying that prompt (`minikube login`) seems to be normal, and it does NOT prevent the `minikube start` from succeeding.

To resolve the issue, this is what I did:

- Delete `~/.kube` directory
- Delete `~/.minikube` directory (in case it exists)
- The **MOST IMPORTANT** step: stop/start the *Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management* Windows service

These steps seem to have solved the issue for me

PS: I used this command to start `minikube` and enable verbose logging:

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv -v 7 --alsologtostderr
```

Answer (score 0):

Farzad, what resources have you used for setting up the minikube? Can you please clarify what do you mean by "unable to start". Are the regular `kubectl` commands working?
For example `kubectl get nodes`? That is of course if below steps won't help you.

The screenshot you shared shows a running VM:

> Minikube runs a single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a VM on your
>   laptop for users looking to try out Kubernetes or develop with it
>   day-to-day.

You mentioned that you've created the vSwitch, you should be using a flag that is pointing minikube to use that external vSwitch:
`minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "vSwitch name"`

You also mentioned choco, did you install kubernetes-cli (as you did not mention it in the question)? It might be the reason why your commands do not work (*seems like the new version downloads kubectl with choco install minikube*):

> kubectl is a command line interface for running commands against
>   Kubernetes clusters

At this moment I recommend stoping the minikube VM:
`minikub stop`
Delete the cluster
`minikube delete`

Sometimes regular `minikube stop`, `minikube delete` does not work so you might have to manually turn off the minikubeVM in Hyper-V, then I recommend to go to c:\users\%username%\ and delete .kube and .minikube.

Use `cuninst minikube`

Restart and install again as specified in the minikube documentation:

`choco install minikube`

`choco install kubernetes-cli`

As for the error you mentioned, let's try to run the cluster properly, and if this persists, we will take care of it.

Comment: Thank you @aurelius for your answer, but it didn't change anything. `minikube` is stuck in `Starting VM...`, the VM at `minikube login:`. When I run `kubectl get nodes`, I get the following error; `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the components as I described in my post - with deleting all traces and trying from scratch? What type of vSwitch have you created? If yes, what does `minikube status` show?

Comment: I've edited an answer, please try those steps and update me if it helped you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried the steps you mentioned: deleting the VM in Hyper-V, deleting the directory (in my case it's `.kube`), but the issue is still there

Comment: I get this error too... tried minikube and minishift (which is forked from the minikube project). The VM hangs at a "login:" prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

kubectl config use-context minikube

Comment: Can you please add some explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. The reason was I chose the wrong disk file to start my VM after creating it in Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

**This solved my issue.**

1. `minikube delete`
2. `minikube start --vm-driver hyperv -v 7 --alsologtostderr`